# Regular expressions with O(N) and backreferences support

Tags: regex, complexity-theory

As you may know there are two different kinds of regular expressions implementations: one uses backtracking (pcre) and the other one uses finite automata (re2).

Both of those algorithms have their limitations: in specific cases pcre can take exponential time to find a match and finite automata does not support backreferences.

Pcre implementation supports backreferences, very inefficient in matching expressions like `/a?a?a?a?aaaa/` against `aaaa`, the more `a`'s expression and input have - the longer it will take and with 30+ of them it will take a lot if time.

Version with finite automata handles all those implementations nicely and have O(N) 
complexity from input, but does not supports backreferences:

pcre time against complex expressions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4gkC.png
NFA handles those, but does not supports backreferences - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2EwI.png

Some information on backreferences support:

RE2 - http://code.google.com/p/re2/

*The  one significant exception is that **RE2 drops support for backreferences**  and generalized zero–width assertions, because they **cannot be  implemented efficiently**.*

Thompson NFA - http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

*As mentioned earlier, **no one knows how to implement regular  expressions with backreferences efficiently**, though no one can prove  that it's impossible either. (Specifically, the problem is NP–complete,  meaning that if someone did find an efficient implementation, that  would be major news to computer scientists and would win a million  dollar prize.)*

So I created my own version which both supports backreferences and has O(N) complexity. It written in haskell and about 600 (~200 of them are blank and ~200 - type declarations, which can be skipped) lines long. It chews through `/a?a?aa/` against `aa` (with 100 of `a`) in about 10 seconds and as far as I know it is the only version which can match

```
/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?(a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaa)aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\1/
```

against

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

in sane (about 10 seconds) time. It of course supports all other features listed in basic regex specification which I found somewhere on the Internets.

The question is: is it really a "major news to computer scientists" and what should I do if it is?

PS: I will show sources in about a week - I still want to run some tests with profiler and replace several internal data structures.

Comment: You can't make a claim about solving a hard ComSci problem that people have struggled with for decades without some proof. Show your algorithm, or your code or just wait until you can. Anything else is just a random claim by a random dude on a random web site.

Comment: I second this ... citing from one of the URLs you posted:  Backreferences. As mentioned earlier, no one knows how to implement regular expressions with backreferences efficiently, though no one can prove that it's impossible either. (Specifically, the problem is NP-complete, meaning that if someone did find an efficient implementation, that would be major news to computer scientists and would win a million dollar prize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are confused. All regular expressions can be represented by a discrete finite automata (DFA) and (because of such) be solved in O(n) time. Perl Regular Expressions (PREG) (and the regex libraries provided by many languages) match a language that is larger then regular expressions, ie: regular expressions exist in PREG.

If you want to look more of this up search for regular languages. Every regular language can be represented by a regular expression (hence the similar names), and every regular expression represents a regular language. PREG can represent things that are not a regular language.

Further, no one likes someone who says "I can do this and it is amazing, but I wont explain how". That alone is reason enough not to believe you (ignoring that you misunderstand what a regular expression is).

Comment: Intellectual property protection is a long-standing and well-accepted practice in the technical disciplines. Don't fault the OP for not wanting to give away for free what he considers a significant discovery.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed testcase doesn't match.  You are not including enough `a`s to match the backreference (only enough to match up to just before the backreference).  If I add 10 more `a`s so that it matches, the regex matcher in glibc reports success instantly

```
$ echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | sed -re \
    '/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?(a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaa)aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\1/!d'
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Yes, it seems, that i messed up a bit when i made this post. There should be 90 'a?', then group of 10 'a?' and 10 'a', then 80 'a' and at last - backreference for a group.

Answer (score 0):

Functional languages seem to have a knack for efficiently implementing regexps.  I've already seen a very cool one written with Common-Lisp: [CL_PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/)

If you can prove the O(n) this might be a interesting result, but you have to be sure that you really have linear time complexity and not being just very effective.

Comment: It solves case for (a?)^n(a)^n against a^n string for n=50 for 5 seconds, and for n=100 for 10 with linear increase between them. I didn't tried matches with higher n, but i will do it as soon as i get home.

Comment: The question is also how it will perform with arbitrary evil regexps.  Your algorithm might optimize just the (a?)^n(a)^n case really well.

Comment: There is no optimizations for (a?)^n(a)^n, that would not be interesting. If you have any evil regexps - please post them here, i'll check and post results.

Comment: you can match aABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA against (.).*(.).........................\1.*\2   --- The first a and the last A can be replaced by any lowercase/uppercase pair.  There are 25 dots (one less than the number of letters in the alphabet) in between.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the article at this link, seems this has already be done by someone else:

[Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast 
(but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Comment: If you carefully look at fourth link in my original post... Finite automa described there works fast, but can't use backreferences.